# jQuery crossfade images infinitely

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, infinite-loop

This code alternates 2 images infinitely, and it works:

```
<img src="../images/opisSlike/nagrada2a.jpg" class = "nag2altImg" alt=""/>
<img src="../images/opisSlike/nagrada2b.jpg" class = "nag2altImg2" alt=""/>
//second image starts with opacity 0

<script type="text/javascript">

function myAnimate(){

    $('img.nag2altImg').delay(2500).animate({"opacity": "0"}, 1500);
    $('img.nag2altImg').delay(2500).animate({"opacity": "1"}, 1500);        

    $('img.nag2altImg2').delay(2500).animate({"opacity": "1"}, 1500);
    $('img.nag2altImg2').delay(2500).animate({"opacity": "0"}, 1500);       

    // this animation lasts for 8 seconds: 2500 delay + 1500 animation + 2500 delay + 1500 animation
}

$(document).ready(myAnimate());
$(document).ready(setInterval(function() {myAnimate()}, 8000));

</script>
```

But I was wondering, is there a more elegant way, so to say, to make something like that?

Comment: I don't know if this is a concern or not, but I'd set it as a single fire event on page load, and set the new interval after the animation is finished. That should avoid any potentially nasty concurrency issues.

Answer (score 1):

```
    function myAnimate(){ 

        $('img.nag2altImg').delay(2500).animate({"opacity": "0"}, 1500); 
        $('img.nag2altImg').delay(2500).animate({"opacity": "1"}, 1500);         

        $('img.nag2altImg2').delay(2500).animate({"opacity": "1"}, 1500); 
        $('img.nag2altImg2').delay(2500).animate({"opacity": "0"}, 1500);        

        // this animation lasts for 8 seconds: 2500 delay + 1500 animation + 2500 delay + 1500 animation 
        // run forever.
        myAnimate();
    } 

$(document).ready(myAnimate());
```

this would be a better solution:

```
function myAnimate() {
    $('img.nag2altImg2').animate({
        opacity: 1.0
    }, {
        duration: 1500
    }).animate({
        opacity: 0
    }, {
        duration: 1500
    }).animate({
        opacity: 1.0
    }, {
        duration: 1500,
        complete: myAnimate
    })
}
$(document).ready(myAnimate());
```

Comment: This is the general idea but I think Dementic forgot the animation is asynchronous.

Answer (score 0):

Use **one** timer. Make it global. Have all your animation based off the one timer. Hand code the animations and leave jQuery behind because it is slow and has issues doing multiple animations concurrently. Wrap the whole thing in a custom library. Make one call from your front end.